# Exclude certain TagNames from * selection

Tags: javascript, syntax, wildcard

Using the statement:

```
var children = document.getElementById('id').getElementsByTagName('*');
```

I'd like to exclude all <BR> elements, is there a syntax for *getElementsByTagName* that lets me do that, or some other nice way?

Comment: [jQuery Not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) would help you if you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with a native function, but you can easily filter.

http://jsfiddle.net/idbentley/ncH95/4/

It would be easier to use jQuery or a similar library (Zepto is a good tiny lib), but if you want to use raw javascript you can use the above.

Comment: Wtf, is `for each(element in allChildren)` legal javascript?

Comment: I can't get any output from that in my code, or when I hit 'Run' at jsfiddle (which I've never used before, so I could be doing something wrong).  I've gotta run now, but I'll do more work on it monday.

Comment: It is, it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in   @Lance, the output is to the console, so you can see it through firebug, or the webkit inspector.  I'll update the fiddle to print the result though.

Comment: Oh wow.. I didn't know that. I'd upvote, but now it's locked in. :\ If you want to edit your answer (make a note that `for each(blah in blarg)` is valid or something like that) I'd be able/glad to upvote.

Comment: Wait, what browser are you using? Chrome throws a syntax error.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's Firefox only.  Another great reason to use something like jQuery to avoid these browser inconsistencies.

Comment: OOOORRR you could just use `for (prop in object) console.log(object[prop])` like normal people. ;) And using jQuery wouldn't make your code work..

Comment: No, jQuery wouldn't make my code work.  I never claimed it would, I just said that using jQuery allows one to avoid browser inconsistencies, which is true.  Yes, using `for ... in` would work.   I probably should have just used that.  In fact, I'll updated my answer just so.

Comment: I've been working on it now for a few hours at home, and with your latest iteration, I'm getting an error in Firefox that "innerElem.get("tag") is not a function".

Comment: OK, I had to change some things, but in the end got it to work.

Comment: You need to add the array index [0] at the end for myChildren.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an framework like jquery you can do

```
$('#id').children().not('br');
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could do:

```
$('#id *').not('br');
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a special operator for that, but you can filter easily.

```
(function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('id');

    if (element.tagName === "br")
        throw "AHHHHH!!! IT'S A BR AHHHHH!!!!!!";

    // Do stuff if it's not a br.
}).apply(this);
```